# How do i monitor which ListView item is selected in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

In my listView i have the itemBuilder value set to a custom widget

```
Widget programsRowWidget(BuildContext context, List<MembershipPrograms> programs) {
return Expanded(
  child: ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    shrinkWrap: true,

    itemCount: programs.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return UsersProgramListItem(program: programs[index]);
    }
  ),
);
```

In that widget the root element is a `Card`, whose child is an `InkWell`. I want to use it's `onTap` property to control if the item is selected or not. How do i monitor which item in the listView is selected from the listView in the parent widget shown above, and how do i allow only one item to be selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- How do i monitor which item in the listView is selected from the listView in the parent widget shown above

You can use bool flags such as isSelected and isSelectable, which is passed to a widget in a builder function. The main aspect there is to separate logic of selection from ListView.builder to upper widget or to object of your element.

- How do i allow only one item to be selected?

Use flags. When one item is selected - the flag of selectable for others can be set to false.

Comment: If i understood you correctly, if one is selected, and others have selectable to false, i won't be able to select another element (which would deselect the previously selected item)? I would like to add that possibility to the app

Comment: This is the part that causes trouble for me, the list items aren't aware of the existence of other items

Comment: Yes, it's all depend on realization of onTap function that you will pass to item. This function can return a selected item, then you can filter items with comparing to this selected item, maybe apply any "disabled" effect to them. And after selection the selected item will be changed and marked in a list as selected

Comment: About awareness: the only way to build that logic is to lift up state management to parent of list view. In this will be an actual list of items (good idea to make them objects), the currently selected item field and method to select one

Comment: Yes that makes sense, that's what my initial idea was, i tried to use a list of flags which size is the same as the list of objects i use for the list view, and in the onTap function i call setState to make every boolean in the list false, and then change the clicked items boolean to true, but it updates only that one item, it doesn't update the other item that was selected previously, which should be deselected now

Comment: Disclaimer: i can't call setState in the parent widget, i have FutureBuilders there so if i call setState the FutureBuilders blink, which is the reason i separated the listItem layout into a separate class(stateful widget)

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing code that cause trouble, but I would advise not to use setState. Instead, it's a good practice to use Provider or Bloc package for complicated state management, which has special builders that listen to current state and rebuild items accordingly. Also, be sure you are using keys on items in list because flutter will rebuild changed items only if keys or type will differ.

Comment: Okay, i'll try a different approach. Thanks for the effort!